# How do I convince the Visual Studio Publish Web wizard that my database is Entity Framework CodeFirst?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

In VS2015 when I open an existing publish profile in the publish wizard, it immediately decides that my default database is no longer EF CodeFirst and removes the option to Execute Code First Migrations and replaces it with Update Database.

Somehow, the wizard seems to be deciding that this is no longer a CodeFirst Project and is replacing it with DbDacFx like so:

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="True">
      <Destination Path="Data Source=*" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="m4d.Context.DanceMusicContext, m4d" MigrationConfiguration="m4d.Migrations.Configuration, m4d" Origin="Configuration" />
      </Object>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

Transforms to:

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="False">
      <Destination Path="Data Source=*" />
      <Object Type="DbDacFx">
        <PreSource Path="Data Source=*" includeData="False" />
        <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\DefaultConnection_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
      </Object>
      <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
        <Source MatchValue="Data Source=*" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
      </UpdateFrom>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

(I replaced the various connection strings with *)

Anyone have any idea what the wizard uses to decide that this is a CodeFirst Project?

This article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx  provides some details of how to roll one's own version of the Execute Code First Migrations option, and is a potential workaround, but it used to just work.

Comment: I cannot answer your question exactly, but I noticed that the problem doesn't reproduce if I restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I've restarted VS2015 a few times and I'm still getting the problem you mentioned here.

Comment: I have the same problem with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

In your .pubxml file, you must rename the ObjectGroup as the full name of your Dbcontext: **m4d.Migrations.Configuration**. Otherwise, it seems to be ignored.

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
  <Objects xmlns="">
    <ObjectGroup Name="m4d.Migrations.Configuration" Order="1" Enabled="True">
      <Destination Path="Data Source=*" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="m4d.Context.DanceMusicContext, m4d" MigrationConfiguration="m4d.Migrations.Configuration, m4d" Origin="Configuration" />
      </Object>
    </ObjectGroup>
  </Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```